# HttpWebRequest парсит только скрипт веб страницы

Tags: c#, парсер, httpwebrequest

Загружаю html разметку веб страницы через HttpWebRequest таким образом:

```
HttpWebRequest request(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://site.com");
request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv: 31.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 31.0";
```

Затем считываю StreamReader-ом этот запрос:

```
string source;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
   source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

На выходе получаю только загруженный скрипт:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за защита, и как ее обойти? Все страницы загружаються через HttpWebRequest без проблем, кроме того, который изобразил на вложенном изображении. До этого парсил с помощью htmlagilitypack - результат такой же.

Comment: Так а что вас смущает? У вас на скрине написано, что страница собирается делать, будь она открыта в браузере.

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужно спарсить веб страницу из консоли. Разве мой юзер агент не эмитирует работу браузера?

Comment: ваш юзер агент может пытаться обмануть сервер для загрузки страницы, но вы при этом получите просто результат запроса в виде текста, вы не выполните на странице записанный там код javascript - а браузер выполнит. Таким образом, чтобы спарсить страницу с javascipt мало подставить юзер агента, надо ещё и сэмулировать браузер - выполнить javascript код на странице

Comment: @tym32167 к сожалению это так. Не хотелось бы засорять приложение лишними библиотеками типо Selenium или PhantomJs. Интересный факт - в robots.txt файле этого сайта стоит allow *. Хотя без настроек юзер агента получаю 403 code request

Comment: ну на крайний случай вы эту страницу можете сами в браузере открыть, поглядеть, куда они вас редиректит, и туда потом и сдать запрос по старинке.

Comment: @tym32167 ковырялся по Network ссылкам, даже нашел Json, откуда подкачиваются нужные мне данные, но редиректа так и не нашел. Я подозреваю, что используют прокси сервер, из за чего такие проблемы с парсингом

Comment: ну у вас на скрине javascript какие то куки устанавливает и перегружает страницу

Comment: @tym32167 это генерация куки, как я понял за загрузку веб страницы отвечает блок Try-catch с if - local.host. Теперь понять бы, как обратиться к веб серверу от hostname